# gulp - cache busting in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-rev, gulp-buster

I have a module named `"A"` which contains all the required compressed files, now this modules `minified` files are consumed by other modules. Is there a way i can implement `cache-busting here for Module A`

My Question is:

Module B's index.html is holding a reference to Module A's minified file like below:

```
<script src="../moduleA/app.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible for **Module B's index.html to load a new version of A's minified js, when ever it changes? without changing B's index.html??**

I don't have any control over the **Module B's index.html**.